# Determine the decomposition of the cokernel of a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

The homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow \mathbb Z^3$ is given, in the standard basis, by the matrix 
$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 5 \\
10 & 30 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right).$
Determine the decomposition of the cokernel of $f$ into a direct sum of cyclic prime (or free) abelian groups.

I have produced a solution and I'm not sure if it is correct. First I found the Smith normal form of the matrix to be $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 10 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right).$ Now, because $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, I can say that $$cokernel(F) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/(5) \oplus \mathbb Z/(10).$$ And because $\mathbb Z/(10) = \mathbb Z/(2) \oplus \mathbb Z/(5)$, I have that $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic-free and $\mathbb Z/(2), \mathbb Z/(5)$ are cyclic-prime and $$cokernel(F) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/(5) \oplus \mathbb Z/(2) \oplus \mathbb Z/(5).$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is, I think